# Вывести модальное окно поверх остальных окон

Tags: css, electron

Всем привет!

Есть приложение на ***Electron***, в котором имеется опция вызова некоего таймера в модальном окне. Необходимо, чтобы при окончании работы таймера это модальное окно ***"выпрыгивало"*** поверх всех остальных открытых окон. Пробовал манипулировать свойством `z-index` в CSS - эффекта ноль. Модалка сверстана во `flex`, вот ее стили:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
left: -8px;
width: 320px;
height: 420px;
top: 40px;
color: #dc2743;
```

Хотя, догадываюсь, дело может быть не в стилях. Буду благодарен за любую подсказку, в каком направлении можно покопать.

UPD: атрибут `position` в значении `absolute`, необходимый для применения атрибута `z-index`, наследуется сверху из родительского контейнера.

Answer (score 2):

`z-index` не работает без атрибута `position: absolute` / `fixed` / `relative`

```
div {
    position:fixed;    
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. К сожалению, не работает и так. Атрибут position:absolute у меня сверху наследуется из компонента-оболочки (забыл указать этот факт в вопросе, сейчас исправлюсь).

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос изначально был поставлен мною неверно. Здесь нужно ковырять не стили, как я предполагал, а сам Electron.